# Drywall and ceiling tile removal in a 1973 home

Tags: asbestos

A guy who I’ve helped with renovation work in the past wants me to help remove walls and ceiling tile in a bedroom of a home that was built in 1973. Also removal of drywall and floor tile in a bathroom. He was told by the owner that the bedroom was renovated in the early 90s. I do not know the extent of that renovation. There is a cardboard-y type wall panel material as well as drywall in the bedroom. The ceiling tiles are common looking white with black pitted speckles.
I am concerned about asbestos exposure. Is there a protocol that most contractors use in these situations? I’m inexperienced and I really don’t want to risk exposure via all the tearing down of these materials. The guy offering me the work claims there is no concern, initially he told me they stopped using asbestos in the 60s. When I found out it was still in use through 1980 I began to question the safety and would like to know if my concern is warranted. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: "still in use through 1980". According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asbestos#Regulation) (scroll down to the US section), it's still legal in some products in the US. If you'll note the picture next to that text section, though, you'll see a researcher working for NIOSH _making_ asbestos samples for testing purposes and he's not all gussied up in a hazmat suit. It all depends on your exposure potential

Answer (score 9):

I specialize in old houses, and most of the houses I work with have had renovation projects through the years, and the exposure to asbestos is a constant concern.

First, you can test for asbestos. You can take samples and mail them to a lab. Around here, the cost is about $15-@20 per sample, which is not bad. Call the lab and ask for instructions about how to collect, handle, and submit the samples.

Having said that, even if there is no asbestos, removing ceiling tiles and old drywall will expose you plenty of nasty things: fine dust, rat feces (and toxoplasmosis), fiberglass, and even lead in some of the paint layers. This is why on every demolition stage, you should use a P100 mask, Tyvek suit, steel-toed shoes, and gloves. I have become so used to using PPE that I actually feel uncomfortable when *not* using it. At the end of the job, bag and discard everything except the shoes. It's a small price to pay, you will work more comfortably, your lungs will thank you, and your mind will feel better. It's all win.

Comment: ...and perhaps hantavirus from the mouse leavings, too!

Comment: All good advice. I would only add that some (most? all?) landfills are required to handle materials tainted with asbestos separately from general waste. IF there is asbestos present, not disposing of it appropriately is a no-no.

Comment: @spuck It's there's asbestos, then this turns into a remediation/encapsulation job, including disposal issues. I don't think the OP will want to be involved if that were the case.

Answer (score 8):

If you're really concerned, take samples and send them to a testing lab. That will tell you if there's actually asbestos there or not. (There are DIY test kits, but for this I don't trust 'em. The lead tests are much more convincing, for me.)

Or you can just assume that it's present and take appropriate precautions.

Note that the fact that your friend works without a mask doesn't mean you have to do so; if it bothers him that you want additional protection, he's no friend.

Others have pointed out here that asbestos, like smoke, tends to be a dosage risk rather than an absolute yes/no, and most amateurs -- especially if you seal the area, mask while working, and clean up with HEPA vacuums -- will really not get enough dosage under normal conditions for it to be a major threat. It's still best practice to avoid exposing other people to it, and to limit your own exposure, but it's not as much of a threat as lead paint can be (especially to young children; nerve toxins like lead are especially bad for brains that are still developing.)

Comment: Even without asbestos, a mask is a Very Good Idea when doing demolition of any sort.

Comment: True! Mineral dust -- and sawdust, and large amounts of particulate matter generally -- are definitely a health risk. Asbestos is worse because it's neither biodegradable nor shaped so the usual mechanisms can clear it from the lungs as easily as most particles.